# Input to Multiple Textbox in Vbsript

Tags: vbscript, textbox

I'm working to create a small application where I've to get 3 inputs and pass them to the script.

As I'm working in vbscript, I'm just able to give inputs one by one.

How to resolve this issue?  Can't I give inputs at the same time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple TextBox for Input in VBScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794600/multiple-textbox-for-input-in-vbscript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Multiple TextBox for Input in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794600/multiple-textbox-for-input-in-vbscript][1])

Use this link.  It's the same requirement.

I would be better if you do some search work for your requirement.